# When creating JQuery Mobile sliders programatically, editable number field does not replace built-in browser slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

As always, some code demonstrates the problem better than speaking:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="stufflist">
                    <div><button id="foo">Button 1</button></div>
                    <div><input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="4"/></div>
                </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#foo').click(function () {
                $('#stufflist').append("<div><input type='range' min='0' max='10' value='4'/></div>");
                $('#stufflist div:last-child input').slider();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first slider auto-initalizes just fine - a number field on the left, a jquery mobile slider on the right.

However, when a slider is added and initialized using the button, the jquery mobile slider appears, but the editable number field does not - the built-in browser slider stays there.

How do I make programatically added sliders have editable number fields just like auto-initialized ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following javascript:

```
$('#foo').click(function () {
    $('#stufflist').append("<div><input type='range' min='0' max='10' value='4'/></div>");
    $("#stufflist").trigger("create");
});
```

`$('#stufflist div:last-child input').slider();` will trigger a create event on the `stufflist`.So all jQuery mobile styles will be applied to the contents of that `div`.

No need for `$('#stufflist div:last-child input').slider();`This is needed only if you do not use the input type `range`.

Comment: I prefer full control over when and how the widgets appear, so I would rather manually create the slider.  I will not use input with type range,so that should do what I want in my original example.  Thanks.  EDIT: No, it still doesn't do what I want.  Thumbs up, since using trigger('create') makes the original example do what I wanted.